# Modifiying IEnuemerable in for loops

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, recursion, dto

How can I modify the nested elements inside of an `IEnuemerable<ProductLineDto>`

So basically the loops look like this `product lines` > `project types` > `projects` > `sub projects` > which consists of more `sub projects` and `activities`.

The problem is I can't modify the `activities` of a `subproject` which is supposed to be happening in the recursive function `GetActivitiesForActivityPerson`

```
        private IEnumerable<ProductLineDto> GetGanttDataByPerson(IEnumerable<ProductLineDto> ganttData, GanttFilterDto ganttFilterDataModel)
        {
            if(ganttFilterDataModel.PersonId == null)
                return ganttData;

            var gdata = ganttData.CopyProductLineDtosEnumerable().ToList();

            for(var i = 0; i < gdata.Count; i++)
            {
                    var pType = gdata[i].ProjectType.CopyProjectTypeDtoEnumerable().ToList();

                    for (var j = 0; j < pType.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var projects = pType[j].Projects.CopyProjectDtosEnumerable().ToList();
                        for (var a = 0; a < projects.Count; a++)
                        {
                            // projects[a].Children is not being modified
                            projects[a].Children = GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(projects[a].Children, ganttFilterDataModel.PersonId);
                        }
                        pType[j].Projects = projects;
                    }

                gdata[i].ProjectType = pType;
            }

            ganttData = gdata;
            return ganttData; ;
        }
```

here is the recursive function

```
    private IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> children, Guid? personId)
    {
        var subProjects = children.CopySubProjectDtoEnumerable().ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < subProjects.Count; i++)
        {
            var acts = subProjects[i].Activities.CopyActivityDtoEnumerable().ToList();

            acts.RemoveAll(activity => activity.ActivityPersons.All(person => person.PersonID != personId));

            subProjects[i].Activities = acts;

            if(subProjects[i].Children.Any())
                GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(subProjects[i].Children, personId);
        }

        children = subProjects;
        return children;
    }
```

When I step through the recursive function, the `return children` statement consists of the modified `activities`. However, this line of code does not consist of the modified `activities` it consists of the original data set after the assignment call.

`projects[a].Children = GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(projects[a].Children, ganttFilterDataModel.PersonId);`

If anyone is wondering what all of the copy methods look like, They just return a new instance of the `DTO`.

for example

```
    public static IEnumerable<ProjectTypeDto> CopyProjectTypeDtoEnumerable(this IEnumerable<ProjectTypeDto> projectTypes)
    {
        return projectTypes.Select(x => new ProjectTypeDto
        {
            ProjectTypeId = x.ProjectTypeId,
            Description = x.Description,
            RowId = x.RowId,
            Projects = x.Projects.CopyProjectDtosEnumerable()
        });
    }
```

Comment: Care to help me improve the question with an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, please submit an executable excerpt of code. For best results, you want people to be able to copy-past your problem code straight into their IDEs to play with.

Also, the code was painfully convoluted. It simplifies to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow_LoopMadness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ???
        }

        private static IEnumerable<ProductLineDto> GetGanttDataByPerson(IEnumerable<ProductLineDto> ganttData, GanttFilterDto ganttFilterDataModel)
        {
            if (ganttFilterDataModel.PersonId == null)
                return ganttData;

            foreach (var pType in ganttData)
            {
                foreach (var project in pType.Projects)
                { 
                    project.Children = GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(project.Children, ganttFilterDataModel.PersonId);
                }
            }
            return ganttData;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> children, Guid? personId)
        {
            foreach (var subProject in children)
            {
                subProject.Activities = subProject.Activities.Where(a => a.ActivityPersons.All(person => person.PersonID != personId));

                if (subProject.Children.Any())
                {
                    GetActivitiesForActivityPerson(subProject.Children, personId);
                }
            }
            return children;
        }
    }

    class SubProjectDto
    {
        public IEnumerable<Activity> Activities { get; internal set; }
        public IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> Children { get; internal set; }
    }

    class Activity
    {
        public IList<ActivityPerson> ActivityPersons { get; internal set; }
    }

    class ActivityPerson
    {
        public Guid? PersonID { get; internal set; }
    }

    class GanttFilterDto
    {
        public Guid PersonId { get; internal set; }
    }

    class ProductLineDto
    {
        public IList<Project> Projects { get; internal set; }
    }

    class Project
    {
        public IEnumerable<SubProjectDto> Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, swapping the for-loops with foreach-loops greatly decreases the amount of code and increases readability. The extraneous copy lists were removed. Moreover, it was necessary for me to create 6 data classes via guesswork in order to compile.

I gave up figuring out a suitable driver for this program. However, I'm confident the problem of modifying nested elements is solved, because the edited variables are only passed by reference.

I think your problem stems from an incomplete understanding of pass by value vs. reference, thus your confusing use of deep copies. Microsoft can explain it better than me, so please check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. I was trying to modify `IEnuemerable` and I was also calling the recursive function with out assigning it to anything!